# While implementing the google Material Design library getting error as Program type already present

Tags: android, material-design

**Error While running the project**
I want to implement the Chip functionality of Material design.
So I Followed the process but I getting error while Running the application.
I refer [this](https://medium.com/@pedromassango/android-material-design-components-setup-google-i-o18-part-1-8894f315b5e) article and [this](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md).

following are the dependencies.

```
 android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.materialdemo"
            minSdkVersion 18
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
        dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'

        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3'

        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    }
```

XML As

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="7dp"
    tools:context="com.example.materialdemo.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:chipText="Hello World" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Getting Error as**

> Error:Program type already present:
>   android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is currently not very clear. Please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve, when the issue occurs and what you've tried so far to solve the issue. Also, have a look at [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers :)

Comment: I have to implement functionality of the com.google.android.material.chip.Chip. So I'm implementing  Material Styles library. but I got the error while running the App.

Comment: Then show us the code of your implementation :)

Comment: obviously com.google.android.material == com.android.support:design ... also com.google.android.material is not compatible with com.android.support but with androidx